# From jscript (or vbscript) how to dynamically invoke a method from a COM object?

Tags: reflection, com, vbscript, wsh, jscript

JScript allows funky features like .apply(), whereby you can invoke a method by name, passing an array of arguments to invoke the method with.  However this applies to JScript (javascript) objects, and obviously won't work on a COM component - but this is the feature I am looking for.

Is there a way to invoke a COM object method, by name, and with dynamic args from JScript?  I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically build the script you want to call as a string then invoke it using eval().  eg `eval("someObj.method()")` or `eval(objName + "." + methodName + "(" + args.join(",") +")")`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Main issue with eval() is that I can't pass in a dynamic number of arguments.  methodOne() may take one argument while methodTwo() takes two arguments.

Comment: @Troy - eval takes a string so you can build it dynamically. I added an example.

Comment: Sorry... my response was not clear :( although you can build the string, there is no reflection available to know how many args to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using WSC (Windows Script Component) I have made a workaround whereby I generate a wrapper script using XSL, transforming the input WSC (which is an XML file).  The XSL generates a switch{} statement with a case for each method, supplying the correct number of args for each method.

Not quite what I was after, but I get better error checking :)